# Is wine still installable on a up-to-date ubuntu 14.10 (utopic) amd64 system?

Tags: wine, 14.10, multiarch

Is there still a way to install wine on amd64?

When I try to install wine, I end up with:

```
$ sudo apt install wine1.6-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : 
Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
libglu1:i386
Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.26) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: liblcms2-2:i386 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed or
libopencl1:i386
Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libopencl-1.1-1:i386
Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libncurses5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
libfontconfig:i386
Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libgif4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libjpeg8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libpng12-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libpulse0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libtiff5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: p11-kit-modules:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to install the correct version of wine1.6 for your Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit operating system. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install wine1.6
```

If you also want to install winetricks run the following command:

```
sudo apt install winetricks
```

wine1.6 is still installable in Ubuntu 20.04, but in Ubuntu 18.04 and later wine-stable is a newer version than wine1.6 and in Ubuntu 16.04 and later wine-development is an even newer version than wine-stable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the PPA and install via the terminal. just type -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then update APT package information by running `sudo apt-get update`. 
You can now install Wine by typing `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

If you'd like to browse the PPA manually, you can visit its [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa).